# Sorting dateStrings in Swift with blank Strings

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm trying to sort an array of custom objects by their date, but the dates are stored as string in **.medium** dateStyle. However, some of the objects also have an empty string as their date.

How can I still sort arrays with an empty date?

Here is my code:

```
let objA = testObj(dateProp: "Mar 13, 2018")
let objB = testObj(dateProp: "Apr 13, 2018")
let objC = testObj(dateProp: "Apr 12, 2018")
let objD = testObj(dateProp: "")

let arr: [testObj] = [objA, objB, objC]

let sortedArr = arr.sorted(by: { DateHandler.shared.convertStringToDate(string: $0.dateProp)?.compare(DateHandler.shared.convertStringToDate(string: $1.dateProp)!) == .orderedDescending })

print(sortedArr)
```

The DateHandler.shared.convertStringtoDate just converts the String to Date, but the **force unwrapping an optional** is causing the code to break when there is a blank string instead of a date.

Comment: Why is there an empty string for that date ? What does that signify ? Today's date ? No date at all ?

Comment: Why you are adding blank string what is need of it? I am not getting it. Can you describe it please.

Comment: Why are the dates stored as strings? Why use a blank string? Make the date property optional.

Comment: @Nitish If I had a list of stores and the date that I visited them, but then I added a store that I hadn't yet visited, then that would be an empty string for the date

Comment: @rmaddy If the property is optional and doesn't exist, does the compare() function still work in this case?

Comment: @user3628240 If written correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extend sorting closure

```
let sortedArr = arr.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    guard let firstDate = dateFormatter.date(from: first.dateProp) else {
        return false
    }
    guard let secondDate = dateFormatter.date(from: second.dateProp) else {
        return true
    }
    return firstDate < secondDate
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Where would this put objects with no dateProp?

Comment: at the start of the array

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution Thanks `tereks`

```
let sortedArr = arr.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in

            guard let firstDate = convertStrDateToDate(first.dateProp) else {
                return false
            }
            guard let secondDate = convertStrDateToDate(second.dateProp) else {
                return true
            }
            return firstDate < secondDate
        }
```

**Convert String date to Date**

```
func convertStrDateToDate(_ date:String) -> Date? {
        let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
        inputFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"

        let date = inputFormatter.date(from: date)
        return date
    }
```

**Output**

Mar 13, 2018

Apr 12, 2018

Apr 13, 2018